# Should I fill stream into a sting/container for manipulation?

Tags: java, string, stream

I want to make this general question. If we have a program which reads data from outside of the program, should we first put the data in a container and then manipulate the data or should we work directly on the stream, if the stream api of a language is powerful enough?

For example. I am writing a program which reads from text file. Should I first put the data in a string and then manipulate instead of working directly on the stream. I am using java and let's say it has powerful enough (for my needs) stream classes.

Comment: What kind of operation you want to do on the file content? I personally think that if it can be done directly the do it directly. No need to do work two times

Comment: @Jonjongot I am doing very basic stuff but java provides really powerful stuff like RandomFileAccess (you can basically do anything with it). I just dont see the point of it. Why not just copy in an array and manipulate portion by portion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream processing is generally preferable to accumulating data in memory.
Why? One obvious reason is that the file you are reading  might not even fit into memory. You might not even know the size of the data before you've read it completely (imagine, that you are reading from a socket or a pipe rather than a file).

It is also more efficient, especially, when the size isn't known ahead of time - allocating large chunks of memory and moving data around between them can be taxing. Things like processing and concatenating large strings aren't free either.

If the io is slow (ever tried reading from a tape?) or if the data is being produced in real time by a peer process (socket/pipe), your processing of the data read can, at least in part, happen in parallel with reading, which will speed things up.

Stream processing is inherently easier to scale and parallelize if necessary, because your logic is forced to only depend on the current element, being processed, you are free from state. If the amount of data becomes too large to process sequentially, you can trivially scale your app, by adding more readers, and splitting the stream between them.

You might argue, that in case none of this matters, because the file you are reading is only 300 bytes. Indeed, for small amounts of data, this is not crucial (you may also bubble sort it while you are at it), but adopting good patterns and practices makes you a better programmer, and will help when it does matters.  There is no disadvantage to it. No, it does not make your code more complicated. It might seem so to you at first, but that's simply because you are not used to stream processing. Once you get into the right mindset, and it becomes natural to you, you'll see that, if anything, the code, dealing with one small piece of data at a time, and not caring about indexes, pointers and positions, is *simpler* than the alternative.

All of the above applies to *sequential processing* though. You read the stream once, processing the data immediately, as it comes in, and discarding it (or, perhaps, writing out to the next stream in pipeline).

You mentioned RandomAccessFile ... that's a completely different beast. If you need random access, and the data fits in memory, put it in memory. Seeking the file back and forth is the same thing conceptually, only much slower. There is no benefit to it other than saving memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly process it as you receive it. The other way adds latency and doesn't scale.